# Changing a SQL column title via query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT product_description.name, product.quantity,product.price,product_option_value_description.name,product_option_value.quantity
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_description
ON product.product_id=product_description.product_id
INNER JOIN product_option_value_description
ON product.product_id=product_option_value_description.product_id
INNER JOIN product_option_value
ON product.product_id=product_option_value.product_id
ORDER BY product_description.name
```

How could I change the title for `product_option_value_description.name` as I would like to name this option.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use an alias like so:

```
product_option_value_description.name AS `Option`
```

If you want to change the column's name, not only for this query but in general use [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE product_option_value_description CHANGE name newname DATATYPE;
```

Comment: If I'm using AS, is there an option to not return the original column name? The default behavior appears to return both the original and the new column.

Comment: In postgres, use `"Option"` (double quotes)

Answer (score 7):

Just write `product_option_value_description.name AS Name` to create the alias "Name"
for this column.

Answer (score 7):

Use `as`

For example:

```
SELECT product_description.name as 'ProdName', product.quantity,product.price,product_option_value_description.name as 'ProdDesc',product_option_value.quantity FROM product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any alias name using the 'AS' keyword.
eg. select **student_id** AS **id** from student_info