# I have many tables and one main one, how can I take there column names from the main one?

Tags: php, sql

I have a tables called "Call", "Win", "Com" and many others the letters in each area the field names. The table named "Main" has all the real names for the fields that are called  a b c .. in the others

```
Call
id  a   b   c   d   e     f     g  h  i  j  k  l

Win
id  a   b   c   d   e     f     g


Com
id a   b   c   d   e     f     g h i j  k l m  n 

Main
id table column   header
1   Call     a             date
2    Call     b             name
3    Com   a               date
4     Com    b               number
5       Call     c                address
etc...
```

My question is how do I do an array where I can display a table of "Call" but instead of it showing as

```
Call
id a  b   c  d  e
```

It will show as

```
 Call
id date     name  address
```

.... and so on the rest of the fields

Maybe something like

```
$a array
[1] =>Jas
[2] => 2017
```

and array $b can be the field names

```
$b array
[1]=> name
[2] => date
```

Something like that
and Ill just have to echo out $b

Comment: Why don't you just call the columns by their real names to start with? This looks like a design smell, to be honest. If you explain why you have it this way, we might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: oh my god sorry Ill correct it now, I have many tables

Comment: Mysql @Prdp I know but I have many spaces and special characters in the names I can't put them as fields therefore I need to do it this way

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ? You are you not creating tables with valid names ? Is there any reason

Comment: @jasy - Am not a expert in Mysql, but this requires dynamic sql

Comment: You don't need to have special characters in the name, stick with the simple names, in english and work with it. In your system you use the special names to use the fields. This is an worst nightmare to work with in a database.

Comment: If you need dynamic SQL/schema, then I'm not sure that you need SQL at all, but might want to look into some Schema-less/NoSQL DB like MongoDB or something?

Comment: Im using mysql, I just named them letters because as i mentioned before there real field names are long, contain special characters, spaces and caps. So this way would be easier @Prdp

Comment: @jasy - No you have complicated it. Now your sql is going to be messy to get the alias names back to `select`

Comment: There isn't a way to do this with arrays? Because this is the only way I need it

Comment: No of course not, this way is terrible worst. You are complicating things. Making what suppose to be easy a living hell. Don't get me wrong, we have enough experience to say this. You let your model layer in the code handle the complicated names.

Comment: Add an example on your question of a real complicated name of one of these fields. And most important WHY it need to have that name IN the database. If you want to explain for what a field serves you just create a simple name and then give it a comment on the database.

Comment: Yeah but also because later I would like users to be able to add field names on there own, is there a way I could add spaces to a field name and it works? @JorgeCampos

Comment: yes it is. just create your table as `create sometable ( \`some weird column name\´ id........` and you will always have to use back cotes with it.

Comment: Let users to add fields on your database is even worst. What is your system some type of phpMyAdmin? It seems like you are getting your problem all wrong.

Comment: No I mean if I want to say `Select * from users` And users contain fields that have spaces, how can I make that work? @JorgeCampos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133699/discussion-between-jasy-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: A `select *` will work anyhow, you just get the field names on your php code. You have to define then with the back quotes and use with back quotes on your php code. I have to leave now. Sorry. Hope you get sense and don't do this. Understand better your problem or even try to explain what your system should do. There are for SURE a better solution for not letting users add fields or don't messing up the database.

Comment: Do not change your questions, ask a new one.

Comment: ok but they said I need to get better ratings, so isn't this how? @YourCommonSense

Comment: Im not cheating, im trying to fix my questions lol @YourCommonSense

Answer (score -2):

you can use as in your query
select id, a AS date, b AS name from call
see this link

[Changing a SQL column title via query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812600/changing-a-sql-column-title-via-query)

Comment: Yeah but they are alot of letters like from A-z then AA, AB, AC... is there another way to do it with arrays?