# Codeigniter join multiple times same table and same column name

Tags: codeigniter, join

I'm having a problem, i have this table named IMOVEIS and another table named CARACTERISTICAS.

IMOVEIS must do at least 10 joins with CARACTERISTICAS, to get different caracteristics (this is a real state project).

Now I know how to make multiple joins in same table, the problem is: the column name of CARACTERISTICAS table (CT_NOME it's the column's name).

So how to change column name to each join result?

Comment: I just found the answer, was asking Google the wrong way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812600/changing-a-sql-column-title-via-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a SQL column title via query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812600/changing-a-sql-column-title-via-query)