# Spark SQL Dataframe API -build filter condition dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark dataframe's, `df1` and `df2`:

```
+-------+-----+---+
|   name|empNo|age|
+-------+-----+---+
|shankar|12121| 28|
| ramesh| 1212| 29|
| suresh| 1111| 30|
| aarush| 0707| 15|
+-------+-----+---+
```

```
+------+-----+---+-----+
| eName|  eNo|age| city|
+------+-----+---+-----+
|aarush|12121| 15|malmo|
|ramesh| 1212| 29|malmo|
+------+-----+---+-----+
```

I need to get the **non matching records** from `df1`, based on a number of columns which is specified in another file.

For example, the column look up file is something like below:

```
df1col,df2col
name,eName
empNo, eNo
```

**Expected output is:**

```
+-------+-----+---+
|   name|empNo|age|
+-------+-----+---+
|shankar|12121| 28|
| suresh| 1111| 30|
| aarush| 0707| 15|
+-------+-----+---+
```

The idea is how to build a where condition dynamically for the above scenario, because the lookup file is configurable, so it might have 1 to n fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `except` dataframe method. I'm assuming that the columns to use are in two lists for simplicity. It's necessary that the order of both lists are correct, the columns on the same location in the list will be compared (regardless of column name). After `except`, use `join` to get the missing columns from the first dataframe.

```
val df1 = Seq(("shankar","12121",28),("ramesh","1212",29),("suresh","1111",30),("aarush","0707",15))
  .toDF("name", "empNo", "age")
val df2 = Seq(("aarush", "12121", 15, "malmo"),("ramesh", "1212", 29, "malmo"))
  .toDF("eName", "eNo", "age", "city")

val df1Cols = List("name", "empNo")
val df2Cols = List("eName", "eNo")

val tempDf = df1.select(df1Cols.head, df1Cols.tail: _*)
  .except(df2.select(df2Cols.head, df2Cols.tail: _*))    
val df = df1.join(broadcast(tempDf), df1Cols)
```

The resulting dataframe will look as wanted:

```
+-------+-----+---+
|   name|empNo|age|
+-------+-----+---+
| aarush| 0707| 15|
| suresh| 1111| 30|
|shankar|12121| 28|
+-------+-----+---+
```

Comment: what if the dataset is huge.. is it efficient way to do it.. or is it something we can do it in the join itself?

Comment: @Shankar For this problem, I believe some type of `join` is always necessary so it can't be much more efficient than this. However, since `tempDf` is always of equal or smaller size than `df1`, I changed their positions in the join and added a `broadcast` for the `tempDf`. This will hint to Spark that broadcasting the dataframe can be a good idea which will increase the efficiency in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for that, my question was is it something we can add the condition in join itself , instead of except first then join, i completely agree your solution is working and i liked it, just wanted to understand in the join itself , can we create a where condition and achieve the same.

Comment: @Shankar Ah, I see. I don't think you can solve this with where since you have a variable number of columns. In any case, Spark will optimize the execution plan so I believe the result would be about the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from a SQL query I would remap the column names in the SQL query itself with something like [Changing a SQL column title via query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812600/changing-a-sql-column-title-via-query). You could do a simple text replace in the query to normalize them to the df1 or df2 column names.

Once you have that you can diff using something like
[How to obtain the difference between two DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-difference-between-two-dataframes)

If you need more columns that wouldn't be used in the diff (e.g. age) you can reselect the data again based on your diff results. This may not be the optimal way of doing it but it would probably work.